# Javascript Google Chart: how to set background stroke color and size?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I try to add background color size and color, but it doesn't work for me. Could you help?

```
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Level', 'Total time in sec'],
      ['Level One',   totalTime ]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Statistics',
      backgroundColor: 'red'

      backgroundColor: {
        stroke: 'green',
        strokeWidth: 5
      },

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));


    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

This code:
    backgroundColor: {
        stroke: 'green',
        strokeWidth: 5
      },
doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Why do you define the backgroundColor property twice ?

Anyway, you miss a comma after "red" :

```
var options = {
  title: 'Statistics',
  backgroundColor: 'red',

  backgroundColor: {
    stroke: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 5
  },

};
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But for example if I want to use this property chartArea.backgroundColor, how can I do it?

Comment: found this : 'chartArea': {
    'backgroundColor': {
        'fill': '#F4F4F4',
        'opacity': 100
     },
 }